# Reset Service Light 2009 1.6 Diesel Alfa Romeo Mito

Tags: electrical, maintenance, service

Can anyone please advise me how to reset the service light on my 1.6 Diesel Alfa Mito?

Answer (score 1):

Several forums I've checked all say that a scan tool is required and that not all scan tools have this function.